# PHP code in Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, static-block

Is there any way to add a simple php code:

```
<div title="<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("manufacturer"); ?>"></div>
```

to a block we create under content page. It can't execute PHP code as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Which php code is not working and on which file?

Comment: the one above is giving me errors of unexpected token <, but when i directly write it on phtml file it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to call PHP code in a static block.

You can do so by calling a phtml file in the static block and write your PHP code in the phtml file.

To call phtml file in static block, you need to write code like this:

```
{{block class="Path\To\Block\Class" template="Namespace_Module::filename.phtml"}}
```

Since you are trying to get product manufacturer, I think you need to use block class name as **`Magento\Catalog\Block\Product`**.

Comment: How may i get the data from this block to my static block

Comment: @CompuScie, sorry I could understand your comment?

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot add PHP code into static blocks**

but you can add a link to your phtml file into static block

- Create your sample.phtml file
- write your code in sample.phtml

Then add this file into the static file as

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/sample.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below instead of your code:

```
<div title="<?= $_product->getAttributeText("manufacturer"); ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null, when i try to get the value by JS, also now it just puts php code to the browser

Comment: Check the updated answer please. title is not for div.

Comment: i want to get the title for the div,

Comment: Please update the js code on your question.

Comment: That code will only work if it is added to a phtml file. Verify that the file you are adding that code snippet to actually has a `phtml` extension.

Comment: Yes this will work on phtml files only. Where did you add this snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will help you:

Basically, you need to call .phtml file to execute your php file or php code;

```
{{block class="path-to-block-class" template="module-name::your-filename.phtml"}}
```

Comment: ohh you can also check the accepted answer above... its also correct

Answer (score 0):

Your above code has small mistake, which is you are including double quote inside another double quote.
Replace your code with the below code:

```
<div title="<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'); ?>"></div>
```